# AngularJS: Unable to define Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started developing with AngularJS a few days ago, and this issue really bugs me.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'NewStudentCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

All other controllers are working since I am using them in other files, just `NewStudentCtrl` won't work.
I have tried a lot of different things, only one worked: defining the controller using `function NewStudentCtrl ($scope) {}` inside the HTML file itself right before the use of the controller. The problem is that I want to split HTML and JS into seperate files.

Please note that the provided source is simplified a lot, there might be little indentation or syntax errors.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="NewStudentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="AccountMenuCtrl">
    </div>

    <script src="js/account-menu.js">
      function AccountMenuCtrl ($scope) {
    }
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="OrtsteileCtrl">
        <option value="{{ortsteil.ID}}" ng-repeat="ortsteil in ortsteile">
          {{ortsteil.Name}}
        </option>
    </div>

    </div> <!-- end NewStudentCtrl -->

  <!-- Loading dependencies -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/new-student.js">
    var app = angular.module("myApp");

    function NewStudentCtrl ($scope) {
    }
  </script>
  <script src="js/plz.js">
    angular.module('myApp').controller('OrtsteileCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {

    }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where have you defined `NewStudentCtrl` ?

Comment: In this simplified version, the definition is at line 30.

Comment: Why aren't you defining it like you define `OrtsteileCtrl` ?

Comment: I have tried that, it didn't work either. I then sticked to the `function`syntax because that worked HTML-inlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Scratch that, something I didn't realise is that angular is happy with mixing them.

The issue is because you are recreating your module several times:

Line  4: `<script>var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);</script>`

Line 28: `var app = angular.module("myApp");`

Line 34: `angular.module('myApp').controller(...`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXpqL/

Comment: I changed the code to use `app` instead of `angular.module()`, didn't change a thing

Comment: Just to check something, but when you have in your question: `<script src="js/account-menu.js">function AccountMenuCtrl ($scope) {}</script>` you don't ACTUALLY have a `src` defined and script contents  as well right? That's just showing the contents of your external file?

Comment: Because aside from the multiple module declarations and the `src` tags, this is fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/5mMxvNf2dNVZ7XQoYG5F?p=info

Comment: That's just showing the contents of your external file? - Yes.
Fixing the multiple modules and another function did it here. 
It finally works :-)
If anyone is curious: I used `var` as a function parameter, not knowing that `var` is a reserved word.